# How to GET photos through localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, backend

I'm setting up a localhost server, and I want to GET photo src through http://localhost:3000/photos/, but It doesn't save photo src to .txt file.

I've already tried in server.js:

```
app.get('/phofn', function(req, res){
  fs.readFile('Photo.txt', function(err, data){
    res.send(data);
  });
});

app.get('/photos/:poto', function(req, res) {
  var foto = req.src.poto
  fs.appendFile('Photo.txt',foto, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });
  fs.readFile('Photo.txt', function(err, data) {
    res.send(data);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

And this in HTML:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var photo = document.getElementById("photo").src;
  $.get("http://localhost:3000/photos/" + photo, function(data, status){
    alert(data);
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: `but I can't GET it` - why? is there an error? perhaps relating to CORS?

Comment: Odds are this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068 
but there's not enough information in the question to be sure

Comment: In your HTML, you are declaring the absolute path instead of the relative path `/photos/` as you did in JavaScript. This may be throwing the parser off because it automatically renders your localhost address.

Comment: @MaxVoisard — That doesn't make any sense. `/photos/` is an absolute *path*. Are you suggesting that the browser will prepend `http://etc/etc` to an absolute URL (i.e. one that starts with the scheme)? Browsers will not do that.

Comment: Actually I was referencing more of what you said with the JavaScript and HTML having to have the same paths with the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `express`. You've defined a [`named route paramater`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) `app.get('/photos/:poto' ...`

`poto` parameter is accessible through `req.params` not `req.src` (unless you're using some middleware to set the `src` property)

```
app.get('/photos/:poto', function(req, res) {
  var foto = req.params.poto
  ...
  // rest of the code
}
```